# Does URLConnection download the file?

Tags: java, download, urlconnection

I need to do some verification on a file before downloading it. I need to verify some of the information about it (extension, MIME type and size). I've got something like this:

```
URL u = new URL("https://test.com/Flight.pdf?some=true&added=8data=7678");
URLConnection uc = u.openConnection();
String type = uc.getContentType();
int length = uc.getContentLength()
String extension = FilenameUtils.getExtension(u.getPath());
```

Does opening the URL connection and getting the data I need will download the actual file?

Comment: It will not download automatically. You need to get the InputStream from connection object and write in your local disk using output stream.

Comment: @AshokPrajapati - I don't want to download it, I just want to get basic data with minimal broadband usage.